# SQL LEFT JOIN with partial string match

Tags: sql, join, advantage-database-server

I want to make a left join, based on a partial string match.

The field I am looking up (REC_LIST) contains (normally) just 1 invoice number. But sometimes, there are multiple numbers listed in the field.

Therefore, I try to do something like this, just find my match, regardless of whatever else is in the field:

```
SELECT DAB700.DATUM,DAB700.BELEG_ART, DAB700.BELEG_NR, DAB050.ANUMMER
FROM "DAB700.ADT" DAB700
left join "DAB050.ADT" DAB050 on DAB700.BELEG_NR LIKE '%'+DAB050.REC_LIST+'%'
WHERE DAB700.BELEG_NR = '337847'
```

In this example, I'm forcing it to find one specific item, just for error checking. Problem is, it gives me the left table - but doesn't find any match (though I know it exists).

Is my code correct? Is there another way to achieve this?

Sample of REC_LIST:

[image: rec_list]

[image: output]

Comment: you can try with this LIKE CONCAT('%',DAB050.REC_LIST, '%')

Comment: hmm I get the error: invalid argument to scalar function: CONCAT

Comment: share sample data of both table and expected output

Comment: Try using `LIKE '%'DAB050.REC_LIST'%'` instead of  `LIKE '%'+DAB050.REC_LIST+'%'`

Comment: Hi, I've posted some data examples. The solution from Package.JSON didn't work, I get the error: Expected lexical element not found. I guess the advantage SQL requries something else?

Comment: You should consider normalizing the REC_LIST column. Wild card match such as this cannot be optimized. It means an evaluation must be done on every row of the Cartesian join of DAB700 and DAB050. If the tables are any reasonable size, this type of join will not work out well.

Comment: Alex W, I think you are right!

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT DAB700.DATUM,DAB700.BELEG_ART, DAB700.BELEG_NR, DAB050.ANUMMER
FROM "DAB700.ADT" DAB700, "DAB050.ADT" DAB050
WHERE DAB700.BELEG_NR = '337847' AND DAB700.BELEG_NR LIKE '%' + DAB050.REC_LIST + '%'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying - but this returns 0 rows, no data. In the end, maybe I will do something else - but it's still an interesting challange for me. There must be a solution, even if not very efficient!

Comment: Your code was also correct. I think the data you requested in the database does not match the conditions

Answer (score 1):

I think your comparison is backwards:

```
SELECT DAB700.DATUM,DAB700.BELEG_ART, DAB700.BELEG_NR, DAB050.ANUMMER
FROM "DAB700.ADT" DAB700 LEFT JOIN
     "DAB050.ADT" DAB050 
     ON DAB050.REC_LIST LIKE '%' + DAB700.BELEG_NR + '%'
WHERE DAB700.BELEG_NR = '337847';
```

The "bigger thing" (i.e. the "list") goes before the `LIKE`.  The "smaller thing" (i.e. the particular value) is part of the pattern.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the logic issue. But still doesn't work. I think the LIKE '%'+ ... is the issue. Does it matter if the field we are looking up is text or a value?

Comment: @egg . . . The `+` is addition if `BELEG_NR` is not a string.  You can use `CONCAT()` instead.